# Redirecting a user with htaccess when viewing a directory with 770 permissions

Tags: .htaccess, chmod

I have a directory called "files" that contains an .htaccess file with the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /assets/secure.php?f=$1 [NC,L]
```

So when a user tries to view any file within the files directory they are redirected to /assets/secure.php file.  This file is meant to check permission on the user but to simplify it all it does now is prints the file name that the user tried to access.

secure.php code

```
$f = $_GET['f'];
echo 'file Name: '.$f;
```

The "files" directory contains other directories with chmod permissions of 770.  Now if i try and view a file in one of these 770 directories I get a 404 file not found.  I've I make it world executable then it echos out the file name as expected.

This set up was working fine on another set up so guessing it's down to ownership or something.  But they all seem to have same group and owner.

The server is apache with cpanel installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can have a `ErrorDocument` for 404

Comment: I wouldn't want to do anything for all 404s, the file should exist.  I don't understand why the .htaccess isn't doing anything when the directory is set to 770.